# Why do we prepend global variables with `window.`?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

In a lot of code examples I see around the internet, global variables such as `innerWidth`, `onresize`, `navigator`, etc., are written as `window.innerWidth`, `window.onresize`, `window.navigator`, respectively.

Why are some of these globals prepended with `window.` and others, such as `document` and `console` typically not prepended?

Edit:

I know how OOP works and that I am accessing various properties of the `window` object. I'm no novice to JavaScript. I'm sorry if my question may have been unclear. I have been programming in JS for years but have never questioned this convention, hence my question.

In essence, I am asking *why* we don't put `window.` before `document`, but we put it before `innerWidth`. Is it simply a matter of clarity? In theory, shouldn't I be able to reference any of the globals without the `window.` prefix and have no problem?

Comment: You need to read the MDN, these are very easy to understand objects. The window is your browser window, the console is your console, and the document is the page document.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I don't think the question is about what each variable represents. Rather why `window` is sometimes used as a namespace.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes.

Comment: *"...why we don't put `window.` before `document`, but we put it before `innerWidth`..."* Why do people do verbose safety checks for the global `undefined`, but they don't for every other global? Who knows. I sure don't. People do weird stuff.

Comment: _"shouldn't I be able to reference any of the globals without the window. prefix and have no problem?"_ Only if there isn't a local variable with the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unfortunate but `window` in your browser refers to one object which represents two logically distinct concepts :

- an instance of [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), an object with well defined properties like [Window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth), logically mapped to your browser's window (or rather the tab, today, but that distinction is hidden from your script)
- the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Global_variables) to whom all global variables are attached as properties

Semantically, it's cleaner to not prefix the global variables, unrelated with the Window concept, with `window.`.

Now note that this introduces a problem when you refer to your global specific variable like `myThing` : it's hard to know if you're knowingly referring to a global variable or if it's declared in some intermediate scope (or if you just forgot to declare the variable with var). which leads to a situation in which you won't use `window.` only for properties of the instance of Window but also for your specific global variables. Of course in practice you'll avoid global variables as much as possible.

Not prefixing with `window.` also has the advantage, when you forget a `var` declaration or a library import, to make your code fail fast in a not subtle way (which is better than failing in production in a hard to debug way) :

```
window.undeclaredVariable // no error, just an undefined value
undeclaredVariable // reference error
```

JavaScript would probably have been better with a distinction between those two concepts (something like `global` or `root` as in node).

Comment: So it's simply a matter of convention?

Answer (score 1):

All the global functions and variables are attached to the object activator, this object dependent of your host environment (browser, node, etc), in the browser environment the object activator is the window object, so each global function could be access with `window.console`, `this.console` or just `console`, I think the prepend is useful to have a more readable code.

You could access to global scoped variables without the window prepend just `innerWidth`.

Answer (score -1):

Think of it like objects. You are trying to get the `innerWidth` of the `window` object its self. `Document` is the same way. You are trying to get those variables that describe the `document` itself instead of the `window` as a whole. And `console` is just that, a console that you `console.log` to for debugging. It also has its own properties.

They may be global variables, but they still belong to and describe a specific "object" that you must call on first. If that makes sense.