# Continuing code after an unhandledrejection event

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, dom-events, global

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event

> The unhandledrejection **event is sent to the global scope of a
> script** when a JavaScript Promise that has no rejection handler is
> rejected; typically, this is the window, but may also be a Worker.

What does the phrase "*event is sent to the global scope of a script*" mean?

Does it mean that after an *unhandled rejected promise* the **script cannot continue**?

I don't understand what that refers to

```
addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (event) => {
  console.log('unhandledrejection');
  console.log(event.promise);
  console.log(event.reason);
});
Promise.reject('sss');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Scope" is probably a misleading term  here. A DOM event is always dispatched on an object, not on a variable scope. However, the `unhandledrejection` event is a global event that pertains to the realm (script environment) as a whole, not to invidivual objects (e.g. the promise that was rejected or the DOM node whose event handler errored). So it is fired on the global object, which is `window` in normal script environments and `self` in a web worker. These global objects are also used as the [root of the global variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26847070/1048572) though, which is why [you can access their properties and methods without dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5460593/1048572). So you can just call `addEventListener(…);` and it's the same as calling `self.addEventListener(…);` or `window.addEventListener(…);`.

> Does it mean that after an unhandled rejected promise the script cannot continue?

No. `unhandledrejection` and `error` events in a browser context are just that: events. They may be handled or not, but the page stays interactive. Code in a worker can continue to receive and process more events.

It's only in node.js where an unhandled rejection (or exception) by default terminates the process.

Comment: "*event is sent to the global scope of a script...*" - So, is that sentence **just** to indicate that the `unhandledrejection event` "belongs to" the global `Window` object? @Bergi

Comment: Yes. But they don't write `window` because it might be a different global object in an other environment.

Comment: Of course, I forgot. But why if the "term" `unhandledrejection` **is an event** is it "shown" as an exception (`index.js:1 Uncaught (in promise)...`)? @Bergi

Comment: Because it was caused by an exception in promise code. There's also an `error` *event* for other uncaught exceptions, and you'll sill want them displayed in the devtools

Comment: Excellent @Bergi. But the `error` event **only** serves to "successfully terminate the script" and yet the uncaught exception still stops the **rest of the script**, right?

Comment: No, an `error` event doesn't terminate anything either in a browser. Of course an exception always stops the rest of the currently executing code/function until it caught somewhere, but it doesn't stop unrelated code. No difference between exceptions in normal and `async` functions there.

Comment: "*but it doesn't stop unrelated code*" - That is, all the code that was already executed **before the uncaught exception** is still working (e.g. the event listeners registered before the uncaught exception), right? @Bergi

Comment: Yes. It's not like the browser closes the tab when an exception occurs…